# How to create quite complicated form in symfony2

Tags: symfony

I need to create form in symfony2 which should look like form on this image http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/805/formy.png/
As you can see there is dynamic list of products and as a part of this list there is dynamic list of options with dropdown list. Just now I have dynamic list of products, according this tutorial http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/form_collections.html and it works fine. How can I add dynamic list of dropdown lists?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

This it not a real solution to your answer if  you want to use the default Form class in Symfony.

But... why don't you consider creating a custom form? Like you do it in HTML. On submit the form, you can get the values just like you do it in PHP...

```
$_POST['something] or $_GET['something]
```